# How do I find the Java Control Panel / Verify it is installed?

Tags: windows-10, java

I upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8 and I thought we already had Java installed, but couldn't find it anywhere. So I downloaded the latest version and followed all the prompts, *thinking* I would be able to find it somewhere on my computer. I still can't locate it (doing a program and a hard drive search). How can I verify it is installed and access the control panel?

Answer (score 3):

- Right-click the Start button and choose "Control Panel".
- In the "Search Control Panel" box, type "Java".
- It should bring up a match entitled "Java (XX-bit)" (where XX is the bit-level of the Java install)
- Double-click that icon to open the Java Control Panel.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To locate the Java Control panel, simply type `Configure Java` in the search bar on the side.

Here are two links to downloading the Java JRE in case you need to download it again. 
[Link 1](https://java.com/en/download/)
[Link 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the versions of Java installed on your PC by opening the "Programs and Features" control panel.

You can get there by right clicking on the Start button to open "Control Panel" and then open "Program and Features".